# GLFW struggling to render 1000 objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm working on a project using OpenGL, GLFW, and GLSL. Here's what my main while loop looks

```
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {


        double fps = showFPS(window);
        std::cout << fps << std::endl;

        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        processInput(window);

        for (int x = -chunkSize.x/2; x < chunkSize.x/2; x++) {
            for (int y = -chunkSize.y / 2; y < chunkSize.y/2; y++) {
                Block b = blockBuffer[x+(int)chunkSize.x/2][y+(int)chunkSize.y/2];
                if (b.state != 0) {
                    if (b.state == containerTexture) {
                        container.use();
                    }
                    else if (b.state == wallTexture) {
                        wall.use();
                    }

                    glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
                    transform = glm::translate(transform,
                        glm::vec3(
                            x * blockSize.x - cameraPosition.x,
                            y * blockSize.y - cameraPosition.y,
                            0)
                    );

                    unsigned int transformLoc;

                    if (b.state == containerTexture) {
                        container.use();
                        transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(container.getShader().ID, "transform");
                    }

                    else if (b.state == wallTexture) {
                        wall.use();
                        transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(wall.getShader().ID, "transform");
                    }


                    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));


                    glBindVertexArray(block.VAO);
                    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
                }
                
            }
        }



        glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        transform = glm::translate(transform,
            glm::vec3(
                0,
                0,
                0)
        );

        transform = glm::scale(transform, glm::vec3(1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f));

        unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(playerTexture.getShader().ID, "transform");

        playerTexture.use();


        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));


        glBindVertexArray(block.VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

I know I'm doing something wrong because, with about 1000 objects to render, I'm getting about 3 FPS(and my GPU should be able to handle a lot more). Does anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

If you want more information about my code, just ask me in the comments and I can share the part that you need, I just don't want to make the initial post too long.

Comment: When you get performance problems, a good tool to start with is a profiler :) If you're on Windows, Visual Studio has a very nice built in one. You can pop onto your favourite search engine to research this. It'll help you find out where the time is being spent in your code, rather than just leaving you guessing. There are GPU profilers too, but start with your CPU time to verify your assumptions.

Comment: 1000 objects? sound like you need BVH bounding volume hierarchy or any other technique to render only visible objects ...

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is super inefficient, here's a few pointers regarding your loop:

- Never query uniform locations, query on shader-program creation and store them
- Reduce texture and buffer switching to the absolute minimum, sort your resources. Also note that buffers remain bound, there's no need to rebind the quad buffer before each draw call.
- Rarely allocate memory, allocate outside of the loop, you don't need a 4x4 matrix to move things in 2D space anyways
- Don't draw each quad individually

Comment: Since I posted that, I've made it so the texture only gets switched if the current texture is not the same as the next one. The main thing I want to focus on is the "Don't draw each quad individually" part. How would I do so? I've looked at batch rendering but it doesn't seem like the right tool for the job. Also, what's the best data structure for 2d position and rotation(rather than a 4x4 matrix).

Comment: This depends on the overall scope of your rendering engine, are you trying to do a 2D tile engine?

Comment: A better structure to encode position and rotation for 2D would be to just use a vec3 with position.xy and rotation α, then calculate the 2D rotation matrix in the vertex shader.

Comment: yeah. Most of my rendering will be blocks, with a few exceptions.